# Не удаляется элемент по клику

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$('.compare').on('click', '.to_compare', function() {
  //add_to_compare($(this).attr('data-id'), $(this).attr('data-section'));
  $(this).parent('.compare').append('<div class="del_compare cl_compare" data-id="' + $(this).attr('data-id') + '" data-section="' + $(this).attr('data-section') + '">' + $(this).parent('.compare').find('.hide.comp_not').text() + '</div>');
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compare" id="31591" data-iscomp="comp_yes">
  <div class="to_compare cl_compare" data-id="31591" data-section="1779" style="display: block;">сравнение</div>
  <div class="hide comp">сравнение</div>
  <div class="hide comp_not">Убрать</div>
</div>
```

Имеется товар, при наведении на товар, расширяется блок, появляется доп. информация и кнопка Сравнить.
Суть этого кода в том, чтоб по клику на кнопку(сравнить), убиралась кнопка и вместе неё добавлялась другая(убрать из сравнения - за это отвечает другой код).
Проблема в том, что кнопка убирается только тогда, когда убираем курсор, соответственно скрывается весь блок с доп. информацией и только при следующем наведении кнопка уже отсутствует. А нужно, чтоб она убиралась сразу же при клике.

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверял этот же функционал, только не на событии click, а на hover и тогда работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает на click?

Comment: ошибки нет, `.to_compare` удаляется

Comment: но в контексте моего кода не работает(частично, срабатывает не сразу), прошу помощи, какие могут быть варианты конфликта в данном коде? как уже писал, hover работает отлично, а вот click срабатывает только тогда, когда теряется hover с родительского элемента(весь блок на скриншоте)

Comment: Создайте [минимальный пример, для воспроизведения проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Без воспроизведения проблемы сказать в чем дело весьма проблематично.